# last-child pseudo classes

Tags: css

I am developing tree view structure in html & css.

Please find the code in the below link. In that 'special folder' there is dotted line missed. I am using css :last-child for ul, li.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtzSF/

Can any body please solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting only direct descendants: `ul#test li:last-child > ul`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtzSF/1/